# Netbeans diff from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, diff

Is there any way to call **netbeans diff** of two random files (i mean they are not in any project in the Netbeans) from OS command line?

*PS
I use windows 7 x64, netbeans 8.0.2, Java 1.8.0_40*

Comment: I use [Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/), an online tool which is very good. You can use that. I don't know about netbeans :/ sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know from the command line, but any two files can be diffed without being part of any project.

1. Go to either the Files window (Use menu `Window` -> `Files` ) or the Favorites window (`Window` -> `Favorites`).
2. If the file you want is not in a subdirectory of any of the shown folders, right-click an empty space in the Favorites window and choose `Add to Favorites...` to add the folder containing your file.
3. Select one of the files to diff.
4. Right-click for pop-up menu.
5. Choose the `Tools` -> `Diff to ...`
6. Select the other file in the dialog.

Comment: thnks, but i (and google too) know how to do it from GUI with my hands, the question is how to do it it from a command line